# Tools icon in recipes in Fallout shelter

Tags: fallout-shelter

I wonder, what means tools icon on recipe image in armory. Here for example.

[image]

Can anybody tell me what this icon means?

Answer (score 3):

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/4axf3i/what_is_the_white_wrench_and_screwdriver_icon_on/)

> That means those items can only be crafted and can't be obtained via
>   any other means.